# More lines are displayed in NodeJS debugger

Tags: node.js, debugging

Having a file (let's call it `script.js`) with the following content:

```
console.log("Hello World!");
```

(so, one line with a console.log on it)

Runnning `node script.js` it outputs `"Hello World!"`.

The problem is when I run `node debug script.js`. I get the following output:

```
$ node debug script.js 
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in script.js:1
  1 console.log("Hello World!");
  2 
  3 });
debug>
```

Why did the last 2 lines appear?

It looks for me like a bug but maybe there is another explication?

Comment: I understand Node automatically wraps your code in a function (i.e. the module pattern) and that would explain the last "});" but I am surprised you don't see a new first line with "function(exports) {" too.

Comment: @HectorCorrea It's only showing a couple of lines after the line that it hit the breakpoint on.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9768

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just showing a portion of the code you were debugging before the process ended. The code you write in node gets dropped into a function which provides it all the variables it needs in that scope. This is how they get around the whole global scope variable problem because every module has its own "global" scope.

A good example of this can be seen while debugging with [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). It lets you click through the assets of your project while debugging.

I created a script.js file with `console.log("Hello, world!");` as the only line. Check out what it looks like inside node inspector:

[image]

---

To install [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector):

1. `npm install -g node-inspector`
2. Open a terminal, type "node-inspector", and the app will start running.
3. Navigate to `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=58581`. You'll see a screen like this:

   [image]
4. Now run your application `node --debug-brk script.js` in another terminal window. `--debug-brk` just causes node to break on the first line of your application until a debugger is attached.
5. Refresh the node-inspector page and then you can start debugging :D

[image]

Comment: Where do you see this?

Comment: This is [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector). See my edit for how to install and use it :)

Comment: A gif screen record! ;-) Nice. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. They're my new favorite way to show something quickly :)